# computer start automatically after shutdown

Tags: windows-7, shutdown

My computer start again after shutdown.
I recognized that this happen only when LAN cable is connected to modem.
But that isn't a good way to disconnect It on every shut down & hibrnate.
also, I mostly use hibernate instead of shutdown.
I tried it on windows 7 32bit and 64bit.same thing.
any information is greatly helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's only happening when you're on the network then it's likely you have the 'Wake on LAN' settings in your BIOS enabled.

Check your BIOS for anything like 'Wake on Lan' or 'Wake on Network Activity'.

Comment: I can't find an option like that in bios.can you explain where is it?

Comment: What brand of computer do you have?

Comment: My motherboard is gigabyte p55 but pme event wakeup is disabled by default.

Comment: I find answer.Problem is from my network card.In it's configuration (from divice manager) a variable named "shutdown wake-on-lan" is enabled. just disabled it and fixed. but this problem can be from bios so answer is good.